# MariaDB select wrong unicode character

Tags: unicode, mariadb, utf8mb4

INSERT INTO `table_name` (`col_name`) VALUES ('');

SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `col_name` = '';

I my opinion no row has to be returned from the second query, but  is returned.

The table is utf8mb4 with collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Is something related to ci? I would like to keep it.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? Even though MariaDB is (supposed to be) a drop-in replacement for MySQL, I would expect that in situations like this the behaviour might be different, so one of the tags should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT '' = '' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
       '' = '' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Yields 1 and 0.

That is, `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` treats Emoji as equal, but `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` treats them as different.

So, change the collation of `col_name` to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.